# Flask's url_for does not quote slashes

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying out Flash and Jinja2 to see if I can use them for my next projects.

However, I'm stuck here:
I have a product route (`@app.route('/product/<prod>/')`) but when I use in another Jinja2 template this expression `{{ url_for('product', prod='abc/def') }}` it builds this URL: `/product/abc/def/` instead of `/product/abc%2Fdef/`...

How can I tell Flask to also encode the `/` when building URLs?

BTW, using the `replace` filter does not work since it will also replace all the other slashes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change your URL route to include a **path** as follows:

```
@app.route('/product/<path:prod>/')
```

This will escape the `/` as required. See the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/76/) for more information.

Comment: I've tried it and it works, but what about additional routes like `/product/<prod>/details`? Thanks :)

Comment: Use exactly the same method? `/product/<path:prod>/details`